# Host cannot ping VMware's NAT network adapter's gateway ip

Tags: nat, ping, gateway, vmware-workstation

I am using VMware workstation 15.5. My host is Windows 10 and guest is Ubuntu 18.04.

Using virtual network editor I created a NAT network adapter as shown in image

[image]

With NAT settings(guest ip is 192.168.180.129)

[image]

From my host, I can browse my guest with https://127.0.0.1:9988 without any problem.

VMnet8 network connection details are as in following image

[image]

I can ping 192.168.180.1 and 192.168.180.2 from guest. Using arp command, after running ping commands, I get following MAC addresses:

[image]

My question is:
From host I can ping VMnet8 network adapter ip 192.168.180.1 but I can't ping gateway ip 192.168.180.2. Trying ping to gateway ip results with request timed out. Why from host I cannot ping this gateway ip address?

Comment: I have the same problem. From host 192.168.x.1, I can ping VMnet8 192.168.x.3 but I cannot ping gateway 192.168.x.2
From vm 192.168.x.3, I can ping gateway 192.168.x.2.

Comment: My problem was wireshark installation. After I start capturing on vmnet8 network card I was able to ping both ways.